# What is the difference between serviceParameter() and serviceLocalParameter() in a ATG servlet Bean?

Tags: atg, atg-droplet

I am new to ATG Framework.
In the ATG Programming guide its explained that the serviceParameter() and serviceLocalParameter() are used to display the Open parameters.

And both parameters set by these 2 are visible in the
 droplet
tag only.

What is the difference between the 2 methods.
Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do some research before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/10639260) answer on the Oracle Discussion Forums answers it the best.

The difference lies in the scope of the visibility of the parameter inside the droplet tags, in particular if you have nested droplets.

It is further [recommended](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2467791) that you use `setLocalParameter` and if you need to pass the parameter to other sections of the page, use the `EL` to do so.